# How do I convert a Blob into an alphanumeric string and back?

Tags: apex, string, crypto, blob

There's a Blob I generated by encrypting a certain string:

```
Blob data = Blob.valueOf('my string');
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, data);
```

Is there a way to convert the `encryptedData` Blob into an alphanumeric string? (something like "vl45v54vnk")
And then back to that same Blob?

I tried `encryptedData.toString()` and `String.valueOf(encryptedData)` - didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use EncodingUtil.base64encode to convert to a String, and base64decode to get back to a Blob.